# Rewrite rule is not working for sub directory in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have domain with name `www.example.com` and I have created a sub directory (folder) with name of `shop.com` so final URL is `www.example.com/shop.com/`
however, `www.shop.com` is working fine.

Now, I am facing an issue with SEO friendly URLs

> I have the following URL : `www.shop.com/tshirt/value.php?url=nike`
>
> and I want to convert it into : `www.shop.com/tshirt/nike`

I am trying to write a RewriteRule for this.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
Rewriterule /tshirt/value.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But this rule is not working. How do I handle the subdirectory correctly?

Comment: try to issue this 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.shop.com/tshirt/nike/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: @PardeepPathania not workded.

Comment: now try my new answer please

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^tshirt/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /tshirt/value.php?url=$1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)url=nike($|&)
RewriteRule ^www\.shop\.com/tshirt/value\.php$ /www.shop.com/tshirt/nike?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```